# Swift Objective-C interoperability on Linux, error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, linux, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to compile a swift program that uses code written in Objective-C on a VM running Linux (Ubuntu 16.0.4, Swift 4.0.3).

I get this error when compiling :

```
fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

**On Mac OS**

The same program works perfectly on Mac OS.

**What have I tried ?**

I've tried reverting to swift 3.1.1 (I remember this working on swift 3 a while ago).

I've googled the problem, extensively, and had no success.

I've followed instructions on how to install the Objective-C runtime on Linux and installed GNUStep (see http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_Using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Linux)

All with no success.

**why am I using objective-C ?**

(Anticipating this question).

I need to call a python script from the program. Python has a library for C, which I can only use with C or Objective-C.

In fact, commenting out the line `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` makes compilation fail when importing the Python library :

```
fatal error: 'Python/Python.h' file not found
#include <Python/Python.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Looks like your copies of the Foundation and Python frameworks aren't in the system header path.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thank you. How can I verify this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift on Linux is not interoperable with Objective-C, it is interoperable with C.

According to 
 https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#c-language-targets, you can have plain C code as part of your package, in a separate target.

You can also link your package with a C library, see https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#c-language-targets.

In your case I would use the later approach and would link your code with the Python C library.