# Embedding Python code in a swift program via C on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c, swift, ubuntu, swift-package-manager

**Motivation**

I'm trying to extend a swift program with some python code and make it run on Linux. 
I'm doing this because I need to include an ML model trained with the sklearn library.

There is Python framework for swift, but I can't use it on Linux.

I've also tried using Objective-C, but Swift isn't interoperable with Objective-C on Linux ([Swift Objective-C interoperability on Linux, error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997335/swift-objective-c-interoperability-on-linux-error-foundation-foundation-h-fi/48008009#48008009)).

The remaining option was using C (use the python library https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html).

**Problem**

This has worked on my mac, but I get this error on Linux:

```
/home/k/Desktop/PySwiftC/Sources/runPyAdd/runPyAdd.c:22: error: undefined reference to 'Py_Initialize'
/home/k/Desktop/PySwiftC/Sources/runPyAdd/runPyAdd.c:23: error: undefined reference to 'Py_IsInitialized'
/home/k/Desktop/PySwiftC/Sources/runPyAdd/runPyAdd.c:50: error: undefined reference to 'PyString_FromString'
...
```

I've tried commenting out the code to make sure the compiler found the `Python.h` header: it did.
Note that I've had to add it to the search path :

```
swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -Xcc -lpython2.7
```

So it can find the header file but won't recognize the functions.

**Attempt at using C only**

I've tried to compile the C code separately with gcc :

```
gcc runPyAdd.c -o prog1 -I/usr/include/python2.7
```

This gave the same problem :

```
runPyAdd.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
runPyAdd.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Py_IsInitialized'
runPyAdd.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
```

until I added

```
gcc runPyAdd.c -o prog1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

This flag was also used with swift build. but didn't work.

**The code**

**runPyAdd.h**

```
//
//  runPyAdd.h
//
//  Created by ** on 03/01/18.
//

#if __APPLE__
#include <Python/Python.h>
#elif __linux
#include "Python.h"
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

char * runPyAdd(char * vectorString, char * signal, char * path);
```

** runPyAdd.c **

```
//
//  runPyAdd.c
//
//  Created by ** on 03/01/18.
//

#include "include/runPyAdd.h"

//TODO: returning errors
//TODO: decision : return string or int ?


#define ERROR "0"

char * runPyAdd(char * vectorString, char * signal, char * path) {


    Py_Initialize();
    if( !Py_IsInitialized() ) {
        printf("Unable to initialize Python interpreter.");
        return ERROR;
    }


    // import sys
    PyObject *sys = PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString("sys"));
    // sys.path.append(resourcePath)
    PyObject *sys_path_append = PyObject_GetAttrString(PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path"), "append");
    PyObject *resourcePath = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(resourcePath, 0, PyString_FromString(path));
    PyObject_CallObject(sys_path_append, resourcePath);

    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    pName = PyString_FromString("fileName");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    Py_DECREF(pName);

    // pArgs: Arguments passed to the Python function
    PyObject *pArgs;
    // pValue: Return value
    PyObject *pValue;

    if (pModule != NULL) {

        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "fnName");

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {


            pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);

            PyStringObject * pString;


            pString = PyString_FromString(vectorString);

            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pString);

            pString = PyString_FromString(signal);


            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pString);


            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);


            Py_DECREF(pArgs);

            if (pValue != NULL) {


                char * returnValue = PyString_AsString(pValue);

                Py_DECREF(pValue);

                return returnValue;

            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return ERROR;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function");
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load file\n");
        return ERROR;
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return ERROR;

}
```

Comment: In this case, it's not the code who is important, but the build process. So, it would be useful if you add the *compile* (or to be more precise *link*) command(s) that you use, any *Makefile*s (or similar files).

Comment: @CristiFati, I agree, added the code just in case.

build commands : `swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -Xcc -lpython2.7`

Comment: These worked with `gcc runPyAdd.c -o prog1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7`

Comment: Never worked with *swift*. Don't know what *C* compiler it uses underneath. You could pass some flags to make it more verbose. you don't have any *swift* code (posted), isn't *gcc* enough?